# Rails 3 and SQLite - handling exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, exception, sqlite

I'm currently building a portfolio with a basic custom content management system and I'm having a problem with SQLite errors.

As the majority of the pages on the site are created using the CMS they are stored in a table.
I want to implement a way of catching errors in the url and rendering a nice looking error page - rather than the standard Rails "Action Controller Exception" page.

I've had a thorough Google and really struggled to find anything resembling my problem. I'm quite new to RoR, so it's not something that is immediately obvious to me - if there is such a simple solution.

If someone could at least point me in the right direction, it would be most appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Exception page with the stacktrace is shown only in development mode.

In production, when there is a routing error i.e. some error in the url as you mention above, it will render the public/404.html page so all you need to do is customize that page to get a nice looking error page.

To test it in development, in the config/development.rb file, change

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

to `config.consider_all_requests_local = false`